# Deploy a Django application on Azure VM using Github Actions

Tags: django, github-actions, azure-virtual-machine

I have built a Django application and dockerized it with Nginx, I also created a GitHub workflow to build the docker image and push it to `ghcr.io`.

Now I want to deploy the docker image (from ghcr.io) to the Azure virtual machine (ubuntu). but I couldn't find, how to connect azure VM to GitHub workflow and execute some commands from it.

```js
name: CI and CD

on: [push]

env:
  DOMAIN_NAME: ${{ secrets.DOMAIN_NAME }}

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Docker Images
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout master
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Add environment variables to .env
        run: |
          echo DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=${{ secrets.DJANGO_SECRET_KEY }} >> .env
          echo DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=${{ secrets.DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS }} >> .env
          echo DATABASE=postgres >> .env
          echo DB_NAME=${{ secrets.DB_NAME }} >> .env
          echo DB_USER=${{ secrets.DB_USER }} >> .env
          echo DB_PASS='${{ secrets.DB_PASS }}' >> .env
          echo DB_HOST=${{ secrets.DB_HOST }} >> .env
          echo DB_PORT=${{ secrets.DB_PORT }} >> .env
          echo VIRTUAL_HOST=$DOMAIN_NAME >> .env
          echo VIRTUAL_PORT=8000 >> .env
          echo LETSENCRYPT_HOST=$DOMAIN_NAME >> .env
          echo EMAIL_HOST_USER=${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST_USER }} >> .env
          echo EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD }} >> .env
          echo DEFAULT_EMAIL=${{ secrets.DEFAULT_EMAIL }} >> .env
          echo NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=nginx-proxy >> .env
      - name: Set environment variables
        run: |
          echo WEB_IMAGE=ghcr.io/$(echo $GITHUB_REPOSITORY | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')/web >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo NGINX_IMAGE=ghcr.io/$(echo $GITHUB_REPOSITORY | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')/nginx >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ secrets.NAMESPACE }}
          password: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      - name: Pull images
        run: |
          docker pull $WEB_IMAGE || true
          docker pull $NGINX_IMAGE || true
      - name: Build images
        run: docker-compose build
      - name: Push images
        run: |
          docker push $WEB_IMAGE
          docker push $NGINX_IMAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up GitHub Action self-hosted runner on Azure VM to run GitHub Actions on the Azure VMto deploy a Django application

Firstly, you need to install the GitHub Action self-hosted runner on Azure VM by SSH into the VM and running below commands:

```
mkdir actions-runner && cd actions-runner
curl -o actions-runner-linux-x64-2.278.0.tar.gz -L https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v2.278.0/actions-runner-linux-x64-2.278.0.tar.gz #Extract the installer
tar xzf ./actions-runner-linux-x64-2.278.0.tar.gz
```

Now you need to configure the VM to communicate with your GitHub account by using below command:

```
./config.sh --url https://github.com/{{Yourorganization}} --token <YOURTOKENFROMGITHUB>
```

You will be prompted through the registration process of your GitHub Action self-hosted runner

Then install the needed dependencies for your Django Application to the VM

Now you can run your GitHub Action Workflow

Reference: [Using the GitHub self-hosted runner and Azure Virtual Machines to login with a System Assigned Managed Identity | Cloud With Chris](https://www.cloudwithchris.com/blog/github-selfhosted-runner-on-azure/)